# What happens when you declare two variables with the same name and scope in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

What happens if I declare two variables with the same name and scope?

```
var foo = (function() {
    return {
        alertMe: function() {
            alert("foo1");
        }
    }
})();

var foo = (function() {
    return {
        alertMe: function() {
            alert("foo2");
        }
    }
})();

foo.alertMe();
```

I'm asking because I'm dynamically loading little portlets on my website and each portlet has its own script tag with a JavaScript module.  The problem is, users can duplicate portlets which  means there is a good chance something like the above may happen.

Comment: this is exactly what happens:http://jsfiddle.net/Damien_at_SF/cQHRZ/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example they're both undefined anyway, so you'll have a value of `undefined`.

Anyway, the second `var` is ignored. You'll have the same result as though you didn't have it, meaning `foo` will be overwritten with the new value.

So, same result as if you did:

```
var foo = (function() {
    alert("foo1");
})();

foo = (function() {  // I'm overwriting the value of "foo"
    alert("foo2");
})();
```

---

**EDIT:** The code in the question changed. The result is now more observable if you run the code. The `foo` variable's reference to the first object is replaced with a reference to the second. The first reference is lost.

Answer (score 0):

last variable will work, 
in your example, first var will be ignored
`var foo = (function() {
    alert("foo1");
})();

foo = (function() {  // I'm overwriting the value of "foo"
    alert("foo2");
})();
`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this problem encapsulate java scripts of different modules in different name spaces.

[Name space explanation](http://www.dustindiaz.com/namespace-your-javascript/)

You can also look at

[How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/javascript-namespace-declaration)